# math.min precision error (found:double)

Tags: java

The following is producing a precision error where java expects a single integer, but is getting a double..

```
if (Compute.isGroundToAir(ae, target)
    && game.getOptions().booleanOption("stratops_aa_fire")
    && (null != te)
    && (te instanceof Aero)) {
  int vMod = ((Aero) te).getCurrentVelocity();
  if (game.getOptions().booleanOption("aa_move_mod")) {
    vMod = Math.min(vMod / 1.5, 4);
  }
  toHit.addModifier(vMod, "velocity");
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Please add the error you're getting!

Comment: Please split your code over several lines, very hard to read on the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

> java expects a single integer, but is getting a double

Because you divide int by double. This gets a double.

```
System.out.println(2 / 1.5); // => 1.3333333333
```

Use `Math.round` method:

```
System.out.println(Math.min(Math.round(vMod / 1.5), 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, but I suspect that what you need is:

```
vmod = Math.min(vmod * 2 / 3, 4);
```

By dividing by double `1.5`, you are invoking `Math.min(double, double)`, which returns a double. The above invokes `Math.min(int, int)`.